# Video doesn't play inline on iOS

Tags: html

I want to `autoplay` a video inline even on iOS on a homepage, but using this code:

```
    <video id="heroVideo" autoplay muted playsinline poster="/img/bc_hero-poster2.jpg">
      <source src="img/bc_hero2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="img/bc_hero2.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
```

It does play inline, but it doesn't autoplay, instead it shows an iOS play button in the center. Any ideas how to fix it, please? The web is online at: http://review.romancecapsule.com

Answer (score -1):

You can't make the video autoplay in Safari, unless the user allow that explicitally 
here is new policies applied by chrome64 and safari11
see:
https://bitmovin.com/play-not-play-new-autoplay-policies-safari-11-chrome-64/

[https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/[2](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

Comment: It does say on webkit.org that videos without an audio track or muted videos can be autoplayed, though.